# JDialog repaint is not working

Tags: java, swing

I have a JDialog in which I wanted to change the components ( like from TextField to JLabel) when there is a trigger ( like button action listener). I tried repaint and revalidate. But still not working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is a sample code:
JDialog has JButton and another JComponent(initially JtextField). when I click on button textfield must change to label.

```
package sample;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @author mravindran
 *
 */

public class JDialogRefresh extends JDialog {
  JComponent c;
  JPanel p;

  JDialogRefresh() {
    p = new JPanel();
    JButton b = new JButton();

    c = new JTextField();
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        c = new JLabel("Hi");
        p.revalidate();
        p.repaint();
        getContentPane().validate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
       /* validate();
        repaint();*/

      }
    });
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
    p.add(b);
    p.add(c);
    this.add(p);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialogRefresh dialog = new JDialogRefresh();
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Here is the answer:

```
package sample;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @author mravindran
 *
 */

public class JDialogRefresh extends JDialog {
  JComponent c;
  JPanel p;

  JDialogRefresh() {
    p = new JPanel();
    JButton b = new JButton();

    c = new JTextField();
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        p.remove(c);
        c = new JLabel("Hi");
        p.add(c);
        p.revalidate();
        p.repaint();
        getContentPane().validate();
        getContentPane().repaint();
       /* validate();
        repaint();*/

      }
    });
    c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
    p.add(b);
    p.add(c);
    this.add(p);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDialogRefresh dialog = new JDialogRefresh();
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: `revalidate` and `repaint` instead

Comment: I did revalidate and repaint to panel and dialog. but nothing worked

Comment: Of course it's not going to work since again you never add the JLabel to the GUI.

Comment: Well, did you add the new instance of `JLabel`, which assigned `c` to, to the dialog at all?

Comment: Got it! Just changing the reference wont work. we have to remove the component and add it again to reflect on the GUI.

Comment: `"Just changing the reference wont work. we have to remove the component and add it again to reflect on the GUI."` -- what I've been trying to tell you

Answer (score 3):

You create a new JLabel here, `c = new JLabel("Hi");` but you add it to nothing, no container, nothing. If you want to visualize it in the GUI, you must add it to a container that is part of the container hierarchy of a top-level window such as a JFrame, period.

Your question drills down to what is the difference between an object and a variable. Yes you change the object that the `c` variable is referring to, but understand that this will have *no effect* on the previous reference that it held, the JTextField, and that this object is still happily in the GUI and will remain unchanged even after changing `c`'s reference.

Myself, I'd use a CardLayout to swap views:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class JDialogRefresh extends JDialog {
    private static final String HI = "Hi";
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    private JComponent c;
    private JPanel p;

    JDialogRefresh(JFrame frame) {
        super(frame, "Foo", ModalityType.MODELESS);
        p = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("Button");

        c = new JTextField(10);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(mainPanel, HI);
            }
        });
        p.add(b);
        p.add(c);

        mainPanel.add(p, "P");
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Hi", SwingConstants.CENTER), HI);
        this.add(mainPanel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JDialogRefresh dialog = new JDialogRefresh(frame);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

Here is the key issue to your problem:

```
String s1 = "hello ";
String s2 = "world";
String s12 = s1 + s2;

s1 = "goodbye ";
System.out.println(s12);
```

If you test this, you will see that the program prints, `hello world`, and this is as it should since while you change the s1 reference to `"goodbye "`, you don't change the original object that it refers to, the original String `"hello "`, and the changed reference will have no effect on the s12 String. Likewise changing `c`'s reference will have no effect on your GUI.

Again, this is a *key* concept: Does this make sense?

Comment: Here you just show Hi. and Button disappears. I just wanted to know how do we refresh the jdialog?

Comment: @MMPgm: this has nothing to do with "refreshing a JDialog" and all to do with your confusing a variable with an object. Changing the reference of the c variable will have no effect on the JDialog since it isn't the variable which is added to the GUI but rather the JTextField that it originally referenced. When you swap the reference, you make no changes to the JDialog GUI. You are misunderstanding how OOP works with Java, a basic misunderstanding that you must clear if you're to move forward.

Comment: @MMPgm: please see edit to my answer. Again, does it make sense to you? If not, you will need to keep working on this to iron this out in your mind since again this is a fundamental Java concept.